# Why the keyboard get locked sometimes when I use Netbeans on Linux?

Tags: netbeans

I am using Netbeans to develop a Ruby on Rails application.  Unfortunately, I have a problem with it.

Sometimes the keyboard stop working and I can not input code in the text editor.
Also the keyboard short cut specific to netbeans stop working as well (such as <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd>)
Nevertheless, the Ubuntu keyboard short cut still work (<kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> ...)

The only solution I found is to maximize/unmaximize the window of the text editor or switch tab.

Comment: this should be a bug of netbeans, same behaviour here (ubuntu 9.4 + compiz) with Java projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably isn't a proper SO question, but have you tried switching from the community version of Java to the Sun version (or the other way around)?

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java

Comment: At first, I'd have guessed that the garbage collection of Java gets in your way but when resizing the window helps, it's probably something else. +1 for filing a bug.